# Что раньше: require или use?

Tags: php

Все чаще стал замечать, что во многих фреймворках в начале кода используют конструкцию `use`, после чего подключение файлов `require` - например `autoload.php`.

Подскажите пожалуйста, чем это отличается от того, если делать наоборот вызовы. 
С начало подключаются файлы, потом use. - мне казалось так логичнее.

И где про это почитать можно ? Что желательнее использовать и почемеу ?

Comment: стандарты psr, там можно почитать

Comment: почему логичнее?

Comment: @Ипатьев потому что логичнее с начало подключитьфайл с  классом, а потом только использовать его.

Comment: логичнее вообще ничего не писать чтобы подключить файл с классом. почитай про автолоад.

Answer (score 0):

Эти два оператора вообще никак не связаны. Соответственно, никакой логики в их взаимном расположении быть не может. Я бы даже сказал, что они практически никогда не пересекаются. Либо это классическое спагетти с кучей require - но тогда ему не нужны неймспейсы, либо это неймспейсы, но тода require в коде днем с огнем не сыщешь - классы подключаются через автолоад.

Чисто с формальной точки зрения, в документации use рекомендуется писать в самом верху файла, хоть это и не обязательно. Поэтому и пишут. Соответстенно в тех двух файлах, в которых require можно увидеть в номральном проекте, использующем неймспейсы, этот оператор оказывается ниже.